# Cómo puedo importar componentes en Vue sin webpack, por CDN?

Tags: vue.js, npm, webpack, vue2

llevo un tiempo trabajando con Vue en un plugin propio de wordpress dónde no dispongo de webpack, por lo que no puedo usar el import, y debo añadir los componentes por CDN, algunos tienen su versión CDN con lo que es fácil de añadir, pero para la mayoría de componentes no existe la posibilidad, y hay que añadirlos a través de npm.

Me preguntaba si hay alguna manera de importar estos componentes usando la versión CDN de Vue sin npm, o simplemente se pueden añadir los componentes que tienen una versión CDN preparada para Vue.

Utilizo Vue 2 y estoy interesado en utilizar VueQuill para mi web.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Tal vez te pueda ayudar https://forum.vuejs.org/t/using-components-with-a-cdn/46855